# Múltiplos filtros usando outro df python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Estou usando o seguinte df

```
# importando o dataframe
url = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ipauchner/DNC/main/kc_house_data.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(url)
```

Após algumas análises eu consegui separar 25 linhas desse df, as análises foram as seguintes:

```
# encontrando os id's repetidos, ou seja, as casas que foram vendidas mais de 1 vez
id_repetido = pd.concat(g for x, g in df.groupby('id') if len(g) > 1)
id_repetido

# encontrando a primeira venda
venda2 = id_repetido.duplicated(subset=['id'], keep = 'first')
venda1 = id_repetido[~venda2]
venda1 = venda1[venda1.id != 795000620]
venda1

venda2 = id_repetido[venda2]
venda2 = venda2[venda2.id != 795000620]
venda2

venda1['id'].value_counts().sort_values()
venda2['id'].value_counts().sort_values()

lucro_prej = pd.merge_asof(venda1, venda2, on='id') # juntando as informações das vendas
lucro_prej = lucro_prej.loc[:,['id', 'price_x', 'price_y']] # unindo pelo id
lucro_prej = lucro_prej.rename({'price_x': 'primeira_venda'}, axis = 1) # renomeando a coluna
lucro_prej = lucro_prej.rename({'price_y': 'segunda_venda'}, axis = 1) # renomeando a coluna
lucro_prej

lucro_prej['lucro/prejuízo'] = lucro_prej['segunda_venda'] - 
lucro_prej['primeira_venda'] # calculando o valor do lucro ou prejuízo
lucro_prej['variação'] = ((lucro_prej['segunda_venda'] - lucro_prej['primeira_venda']) / 
lucro_prej['primeira_venda'] * 100).round(decimals = 2) # calculando a % do lucro ou prejuízo
lucro_prej.sort_values(by=['variação'], ascending=False, inplace = True) # ordenando em ordem crescente
lucro_prej

maiores_lucros = lucro_prej.head(25)
maiores_lucros
```

Isso gerou outro df (maiores_lucros) com 25 linhas.

O que eu fiz foi múltiplos filtros no df originla(df). Por exemplo: bathrooms >=1 e <=3, bedrooms >= 2 e <=4. Essa parte eu consegui com o seguinte código:

```
lista_casas = df[((df.bedrooms > 2) & (df.bedrooms < 6)) & (df.bathrooms >= 1) & (df.bathrooms <= 3)]
```

Mas o que eu precisava era fazer um filtro para que os id's do df maiores_lucros não aparecessem no lista_casas. Até tentei da seguinte maneira:

```
id_filtrar = maiores_lucros['id'].tolist()
id_filtrar

lista_casas2 = df[df.id != id_filtrar]
lista_casas2
```

Mas retorna o seguinte erro:

```
ValueError: ('Lengths must match to compare', (21528,), (25,))
```

Existe alguma maneira de fazer esse filtro?

Comment: Conforme a resposta do @PauloMarques, é erro de uso, portanto estou fechando. Obrigado por compreenderem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema do seu código é que você está querendo comparar um código com uma lista.

```
lista_casas2 = df[df.id != id_filtrar]
                  -----    ----------
                    |           |
                  código      lista
```

O certo seria:

```
lista_casas2 = df[~df.id.isin(id_filtrar)]
```

Onde `~` representa **NOT**